# How to remove local storage data after uninstallation of the application from smart Tv

Tags: javascript

How to remove local storage data after uninstallation of the application from smart Tv !

I followed this guide !

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tec00111/index.html#contents

I created a file "MyReset.js" in the main folder of the application ! and I put this code :

```
MyReset.reset = function() {
    localStorage.clear();
};
```

and in config.xml I added this ligne :

`<deleteJS>` MyReset `</deleteJS>`

And nothing happen ! the local storage data is still here !

I did something wrong ?

Is there another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var fileSystemObj = new FileSystem();
var bResult = fileSystemObj.deleteCommonFile(curWidget.id + '/testFile.data');
```

From http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/index.html?Foldername=ref00001&Filename=deletecommonfile.html